# Javascript not being loaded in Django, but css and img do

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

well, as the title suggests, I have a carousel I want in my index page, so I originally went for owl-carousel, but it wasn't working, so I decided to use the bootstrap carousel and I'm having exactly the same issue.
It can't be that I didn't declare correctly the root, because I use a link (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js), so I really don't know what the problem is, let me show you...

### What it should look like

[image]

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
template_name = "core/index.html"
```

### Owl-carousel:

#### The code:

[image]

#### The result:

[image]

### Bootstrap carousel

#### Here the issue is that the buttons in the result are not working.

#### The code:

[image]

#### The result:

[image]

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thank you.